# postgres How to generate a recursive json string from a normalized, self-referential table

Tags: postgresql

I have a self-referencing table like:

```
create table foo (
    id int primary key, 
    name varchar(10) not null, 
    parent_id int null references foo (id)
);

insert into foo values 
    (1, 'a', null), 
    (2, 'b', 1), 
    (3, 'c', 1), 
    (4, 'd', 2), 
    (5, 'e', 3), 
    (6, 'f', 3), 
    (7, 'g', 4)
;

select * from foo;

id  | name | parent_id
1   |  a   | 
2   |  b   | 1
3   |  c   | 1
4   |  d   | 2
5   |  e   | 3
6   |  f   | 3
7   |  g   | 4
```

Given a top level row (where parent_id is null, so in this example `where id=1`), I would like to generate a recursive json string like this:

```
{
    "1": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "a",
        "children": {
            "2": {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "b",
                "children": {
                    "4": {
                        "id": 4,
                        "name": "d",
                        "children": {
                            "7": {
                                "id": 7,
                                "name": "g",
                                "children": {}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "3": {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "c",
                "children": {
                    "5": {
                        "id": 5,
                        "name": "e",
                        "children": {}
                    },
                    "6": {
                        "id": 6,
                        "name": "f",
                        "children": {}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you realy want to have "children" as object and not as array ?

Comment: @JuliusTuskenis I would be fine with an array so long as the outside is consistent by also being an array. For example `[{"id": 1, "name": a", "children": [{"id": 2, "name": "b", "children": [...]}]}]`